# Prove that any semisimple Lie algebra can be generated with two elements

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I saw this question on a previous test paper of Lie algebra. I tried using Cartan decomposition yet got no clue what to do next.

Comment: Are the Lie algebras over $\Bbb C$? You can use the classification.

Comment: Finite dimensional, I guess?

Answer (score 9):

Over an arbitrary field we have the following result:

**Theorem:** Let $L$ be a finite-dimensional simple Lie algebra in characteristic $p\neq 2,3$. Then $L$ is generated by $2$ elements.

*Proof*: See [here](https://sfb701.math.uni-bielefeld.de//preprints/sfb07056.pdf), Theorem A.

For a proof for semisimple Lie algebras in characteristic zero see Kuranishi's proof [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1118764740), §2, Theorem $6$.

Comment: In fact, Kuranishi's proof cited above is stated and works over any field of characteristic $0$.

Comment: @JoseBrox Yes, thank you.