# Is it possible to have two finite order topological generators of a noncompact Lie group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

What is an example of a noncompact Lie group $ G $ and two finite order elements $ a,b \in G $ such that the closure (in the manifold topology) of the subgroup $ <a,b> $ is all of $ G $?

Ideally the example would be a matrix group $ G $ and $ a,b $ would be given explicitly as finite order matrices.

It turns out that such a pair of finite order elements always exists if $ G $ is compact semisimple

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431456/semisimple-compact-lie-group-topologically-generated-by-two-finite-order-element/444664#444664

For example $$
a=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
b=\begin{bmatrix} \overline{\zeta_{16}} & 0 \\ 0 & \zeta_{16} \end{bmatrix}
$$
generate a dense subgroup of $ SU_2 $.

Comment: Does $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual generators work or am I mistaken?

Comment: Never mind, I see I missed the finite order requirement.

Comment: $SL(2,R)$ will work.

Comment: @MoisheKohan ya I was wondering about that maybe since $ S, ST $ are finite order and generate $ SL(2,Z) $ then $ \sqrt{S}, ST $ would be finite order and maybe be topological generators for $ SL(2,R) $? Where $ S, T $ are the standard generators for the modular group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group

Comment: Just take any two fixed finite order elements which do not commute and whose fixed points are close enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to find such examples in, say, $G=PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$. First of all, if $a, b$ are noncommuting elements of finite order $\ge 3$, they generate a Zariski dense subgroup (this is a nice exercise in understanding Lie subgroups of $G$). Now, you just have to choose $a, b$ so that they generate a nondiscrete subgroup. For instance, take them both the **Zassenhaus neighborhood** of $1\in G$. Or, if you prefer, make them violate the Kazhdan-Margulis lemma: Fix the order and make sure that the fixed points in the hyperbolic plane are close enough. Or make $a, b$ violate the [Jorgensen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B8rgensen%27s_inequality)...

With more thought, you will realize that such elements exist in any complex semisimple Lie group $G$. The key is to observe that **compact** elements of the Lie algebra form a Zariski dense subset. Then you use the fact that if $a, b\in G$ generate a nondiscrete subgroup and $\log(a), \log(b)$ generate the Lie algebra of $G$, then $a, b$ generate a dense subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Does your result from the second paragraph also apply to all real algebraic semisimple Lie groups $ G $? Would you be interested in posting your argument from the second paragraph as an answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537024/simple-lie-group-topologically-generated-by-two-finite-order-elements ?

Comment: I do not know about all real, I wrote only about complex Lie groups.