# Constructing a basis for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ that spans a specific subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

## Question:

For every pair of linearly independent, $n\times n $, skew-Hermitian matrices $A, B\in \mathfrak{su}(n)$ with $[A,B]\neq 0$, does there exist a basis that spans $A$ and $B$ over the real numbers but which also satisfies the commutation relations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ (or $\mathfrak{u}(2)$)? If so, how do we construct it?

I feel like there is a simple answer that I am not seeing.

### What I have tried:

- Finding a basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ for $\mathrm{span}(\{A,B\})$ alone can be done via Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization, but this basis will clearly not span $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.
- Realize that $\mathfrak{su}(n) = \mathfrak{h}\oplus\mathfrak{h_+}\oplus\mathfrak{h_-}$. I can pick $A$ to be in $\mathfrak{h}$ and then expand $B$ in a basis for $\mathfrak{h}$, $\mathfrak{h_+}$ and $\mathfrak{h_-}$. I think there exists a basis where $B$ only has support on a single element of both $\mathfrak{h}_\pm$, but I can't show that this is the case. If I did however, I think those 3 elements could all be chosen so that they satisfy $\mathfrak{su}(2)$'s commutation relations.

Comment: If you take two generic matrices $A, B$ then they will generate the entire $su(n)$. Hence, you will never find your basis unless $n=2$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771280/prove-that-any-semisimple-lie-algebra-can-be-generated-with-two-elements

Comment: I know that $A$ and $B$ would generate all of $\mathfrak{su}$. But my question has to do with the vector space $\mathrm{span}\{A,B\}$. Maybe a different way of phrasing the question is: Can $\mathrm{span}\{A,B\} \subset \mathfrak{su}(2) \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{su}(n)$?

Comment: It is the same question. Just think about it. Unless you are asking if su(n) contains copies of su(2). This of course is true. My suggestion is to rewrite your question avoiding the word "given" and using instead "there exist" or "for every."

Comment: I will do that and think more about what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are asking the following:

Is it true that for every pair of noncommuting elements $A, B\in su(n)$, the linear span $Span(\{A,B\})$ is contained in a subalgebra isomorphic to $su(2)$?

The answer to this question is negative (unless $n=2$ of course). Namely, take two elements $A, B\in su(n)$ which generate $su(n)$ (i.e. the smallest Lie subalgebra of $su(n)$ containing $A, B$ equals the entire $su(n)$). For the existence of such $A, B$, see  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771280/prove-that-any-semisimple-lie-algebra-can-be-generated-with-two-elements). Clearly, such $A, B$ cannot commute, otherwise they generate a commutative subalgebra.

Since $A, B$ generate $su(n)$ and $su(n)$ is not isomorphic to $su(2)$ (unless $n=2$), we conclude that $\{A, B\}$ is not contained in a subalgebra isomorphic to $su(2)$.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you.